# WPF Binding slider and textbox values to static int value

Tags: c#, wpf

I have two `public static int` variables that are declared (they were constants, but need to be changed, so I made them static):

```
    public static int CELLS_X = 381;
    public static int CELLS_Y = 185;
```

I need to bind these to my slider and textbox, how would I do this?

```xml
<TextBox Width="70" 
         Text="{Binding ElementName=cellSizesSlider, Path=Value, Mode=TwoWay}" 
         Margin="5" />

<Slider x:Name="cellSizesSlider" 
        Width="100" 
        Margin="5" 
        Minimum="0"
        Maximum="400" 
        TickPlacement="BottomRight" 
        TickFrequency="10" 
        IsSnapToTickEnabled="True" 
        Value="{Binding Path=CELLS_X, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

I'm only binding `CELLS_X` in the slider because I don't care what Y is at the moment.

**Edit**

They're static because I use them in various places of my code to declare the initial grid size of my Conway's Game of Life board. They were constants that I was using for the grid size of initial startup, but I want it to be dynamic.

They are being declared at the top of the MainWindow class:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window {

    public const double CELL_SIZE = 5;
    public static int CELLS_X = 381;
    public static int CELLS_Y = 185;
    private BoardModel model = new BoardModel();

    public MainWindow() {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.model.Update += new BoardModel.OnUpdate(model_Update);

        ConwaysLifeBoard.Width = (MainWindow.CELL_SIZE * MainWindow.CELLS_X) + 40;
        ConwaysLifeBoard.Height = (MainWindow.CELL_SIZE * MainWindow.CELLS_Y) + 100;
    }

    // Details elided
}
```

Comment: Where are these static fields declared?

Comment: Why do they have to be static at all?

Comment: Okay, use 4 fields: `public static int initialCellsX = 381;` then `public int CELLS_X;`. Declare CELLS_X as initialCellsX for initial sizing. With binding you usually have them in a class that is passed into items like a GridViewColumn item. `<GridViewColumn Width="80" Header="Category" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Category}" />`

Comment: @Technocrat - You can't bind TwoWay with fields, you have to use properties for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you cannot bind to fields, so you'll need to convert your field to a property.  Even if you do this, though, you are not going to get a change notification for the static property.  One way around that is to create and raise a `PropertyNameChanged` static event.  This would become untenable for more than a handful of properties.

```
private static int _cellsX = 381;

// Static property to bind to
public static int CellsX {
     get{return _cellsX;} 
     set{
        _cellsX = value;
        RaiseCellsXChanged();
    }
}

// Static event to create change notification
public static event EventHandler CellsXChanged;

// Event invocator
private static void RaiseCellsXChanged() {
    EventHandler handler = CellsXChanged;
    if (handler != null) {
        handler(null, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

And the XAML

```xml
<Slider x:Name="cellSizesSlider" 
    Width="100" 
    Margin="5" 
    Minimum="0"
    Maximum="400" 
    TickPlacement="BottomRight" 
    TickFrequency="10" 
    IsSnapToTickEnabled="True" 
    Value="{Binding Path=CellsX}"/>
```